# Static import with wildcard

Tags: java, import, static

I was wondering if it is possible in Java to use static import with wildcards?

e.g.:

`import static java.util.Arrays.*;`

Comment: Why not try it?

Comment: My code formatter won't let me do it.  Well, it will, but it "corrects" it to the specific classes I need.  Rats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes that is possible.

Static imports are for importing static members of classes. Just like regular imports, you can use a wildcard or import a specific member.

example

```
import static java.util.Arrays.asList; // importing static member asList
import static java.util.Arrays.* ; // importing all static members of Arrays class
```

Answer (score 3):

You can. The `import static` will import all static members from the class. For example with `Math`:

```
import static java.lang.Math.*; // Imports all static members from Math

boolean isSmaller = E < PI;
```

If you didn't do this you would have to write:

```
boolean isSmaller = Math.E < Math.PI;
```

You should use static imports rarely though, as they tend to make your code harder to read. For a constants class it's okay to do it, if you use the constants a lot, but don't overuse it!